# Getting Error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'egt1egt' to data type int. "

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created one sql procedure to return password associated with user name.

SQL Procdure:

```
USE [C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\ADDMARKER\MAP\MAP\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_EmailPassword]    Script Date: 10/18/2012 15:32:02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_EmailPassword] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
            (
            @UserName  nvarchar(256),
            @PasswordReturn nvarchar(128) out
            )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
     DECLARE @UserId                                 uniqueidentifier
     DECLARE @Password                               nvarchar(128)
     DECLARE @Return_Password                         nvarchar(256)
     DECLARE @IsLockedOut                            bit
     DECLARE @ErrorCode     int
     SET @ErrorCode = 0

     DECLARE @TranStarted   bit
     SET @TranStarted = 0
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF( @@TRANCOUNT = 0 )
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        SET @TranStarted = 1
    END
    ELSE
        SET @TranStarted = 0

    SELECT  @UserId = u.UserId,
            @Password = m.Password,
            @IsLockedOut = m.IsLockedOut

    FROM    dbo.aspnet_Users u, dbo.aspnet_Membership m WITH ( UPDLOCK )
    WHERE    u.UserId = m.UserId AND
            LOWER(@UserName) = u.LoweredUserName

     IF ( @@rowcount = 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = 1
    END

    IF( @IsLockedOut = 1 )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = 99
    END
    IF(Not( @ErrorCode = 0) )
    set @PasswordReturn = 'Error in search'
       ELSE
       set @PasswordReturn = @Password
       RETURN @PasswordReturn
END
```

I am getting error

> "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure aspnet_Membership_EmailPassword, Line 59
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'egt1egt' to data type int."

On execution of that procedure.

Please can any one help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Return` can only return an int which is the return value of the procedure.

The output parameter will be automatically returned when you exit the procedure, so remove the line

```
 RETURN @PasswordReturn
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99(v=vs.71).aspx for a detailed explanation of the difference between output parameters and the return value

Comment: Thanks!!
Then how can I pass password which I got from this procedure?
I want that password in ASP.net program. Sorry I am new to SQL server programming

Comment: It will be in the `@PasswordReturn` parameter.

Comment: I am getting one more error now:
"Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure aspnet_Membership_EmailPassword, Line 0
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1."

Code is same except return statement. What might be issue?

Comment: You've started the transaction at the start but not called `commit` or `rollback`